# Android spinner short click on item + context menu

Tags: android, contextmenu, spinner

I wont show context menu if user have short click on spinner's item:

```
    uSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Position = " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            pos = position;
            registerForContextMenu(view); 
            openContextMenu(view);
            unregisterForContextMenu(view);
        }
    });
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo info)
    {
        if(pos != -1)
        {
            menu.setHeaderTitle("Admin menu");
            menu.add("Kick");
        }       
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        if(item.getTitle()=="Kick")
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Kick: " + usrStack.get(pos), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);  
    }
```

All is fine, but I see this context menu for first element if my app starts.
(As you probably remember, kind anonymous, the first element is shown on the spinner. So I think it select this first element and call my context menu)
How to show it only onlick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to add a boolean flag to your onItemSelected callback.

```
if (!isfirst){
    openContextMenu(spinner);                   
} else {
    isfirst = false;
}
```

You will also encounter a second problem with your spinner, where because the first item  is selected by default, clicking it won't 'trigger' the callback method. The way around this is to insert a blank item at the head of your list and check for this in your callback too.

```
 if (position != 0){
    openContextMenu(spinner);                   
} else {
    // Do nothing
}
```

edit: I also noticed you are registering each view for the context menu every time you click an item. You only need to register the spinner once, after you've defined it, then pass the spinner as the view when you call openContextMenu(spinner)